# intel x86 array content

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm doing a program in assembly for a project with intel x86, i need to get to the content of an array, i have the first position but i need to get the another index, and save it in a register, so what im doing is: `

```
call calcIndexP1         ; this calculates the index of the array and saves the value in  indexMat
mov bl, [mineField]      ; this is the first position of array 
lea  ebx, [ebx+indexMat] ; here I load the adress of the array position 
mov ebx, ebx             ; i think with this i get the content of the ebx which is the position of array 
cmp ebx, 1               ; I compare its value with 1 and jmp to some other states
je  mina
jmp no_mina`
```

But I can't get its content.
I guess this is because it always does the unconditional jump, even when the value is 1.

Comment: You have messed up the operand sizes. Also `mov ebx, ebx ` makes no sense you probably meant `mov ebx, [ebx]`. Based on your description I think you more likely want `mov ebx, [indexMat]; mov bl, [mineField+ebx]; cmp bl, 1`.

Comment: @Jester I tried what u say, but it gives me an error on the instruction mov bl,[mineField+ebx], it says there's a infringement of access on reading the location 0x01531041.

Answer (score 0):

Solution depends on how you defined *mineField*

*mineField* points to the (bytes ?) array itself:

```
call calcIndexP1         ; calculates the index of the array
mov eax, [indexMat]
mov bl, [mineField+eax]  ; Content 
cmp bl, 1                ; I compare its value with 1 and jmp to some other states
je  mina
jmp no_mina
```

*mineField* is a variable whose content points to the (bytes ?) array:

```
call calcIndexP1         ; calculates the index of the array
mov eax, [indexMat]
mov ebx, [mineField]     ; this is the first position of array 
mov bl, [ebx+eax]        ; Content 
cmp bl, 1                ; I compare its value with 1 and jmp to some other states
je  mina
jmp no_mina
```